# Node + Json validate key nested array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation

I have sample json. In that json I need to check the following things.

1. Valid Json or not.
2. Name key is required without empty(list name and item name).
3. items array length need to greater than 5.

I attached my code and its not working. I feel this approach is not good. Can anyone please suggest to me the correct path.

```js
var test = '{ "lists": [ { "items": [ { "name": "Curd0", "sequence": 3 }, { "name": "Curd1", "sequence": 2 }, { "name": "Curd2", "sequence": 1 }, { "name": "Curd3", "sequence": 4 }, { "name": "Curd4", "sequence": 10 }, { "name": "Curd5", "sequence": 9 }, { "name": "Curd6", "sequence": 8 }, { "name": "Curd7", "sequence": 7 }, { "name": "Curd8", "sequence": 6 }, { "name": "Curd9", "sequence": 5 } ], "name": "Curd Family", "status": "new", "created_by": 100036, "created_on": "2016-05-05T13:18:26.169Z" }, { "items": [ { "name": "Milk0", "sequence": 3 }, { "name": "Milk1", "sequence": 2 }, { "name": "Milk2", "sequence": 1 }, { "name": "Milk3", "sequence": 4 }, { "name": "Milk4", "sequence": 10 }, { "name": "Milk5", "sequence": 9 }, { "name": "Milk6", "sequence": 8 } ], "name": "Milk Family", "status": "new", "created_by": 100036, "created_on": "2016-05-05T13:18:44.504Z" }, { "items": [ { "name": "Water0", "sequence": 3 }, { "name": "Water1", "sequence": 2 }, { "name": "Water2", "sequence": 1 }, { "name": "Water3", "sequence": 4 }, { "name": "Water4", "sequence": 10 }, { "name": "Water5", "sequence": 9 }, { "name": "Water6", "sequence": 8 } ], "name": "Water Family", "status": "new", "created_by": 100036, "created_on": "2016-05-05T13:19:02.329Z" }, { "items": [ { "name": "Fruit0", "sequence": 3 }, { "name": "Fruit1", "sequence": 2 }, { "name": "Fruit2", "sequence": 1 }, { "name": "Fruit3", "sequence": 4 } ], "name": "Fruit Family", "status": "new", "created_by": 100036, "created_on": "2016-05-05T13:19:15.503Z" } ] }';


function Validate(data, callback) {

    for (index in lists) {
        if (!lists.index.hasOwnProperty('name')) {
            callback("Name cannot be empty");
        }

        var itemList = lists.index.items;
        if (itemList.length < 5) {
            callback("List need more than 5 lenth");
        }
        for ( i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
            if (!itemList[i].hasOwnProperty('name')) {
                callback("Item Name cannot be empty");
            }
        }

    }
    callback(null);
}


Validate(test, function (err) {

    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: does json-schema can help you ? http://json-schema.org/ see also https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[every](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/every) is probably what you need :

```
function containsNameInLists(element) {
  return element.hasOwnProperty('name');
}

function containsNameInItems(element) {
    return element.items.every(containsKeyName);
}

function containsKeyName(element) {
    return element.hasOwnProperty('name');
}

function lengthSuperiorTo5(element) {
    return element.length > 5;
}

function itemsArrayLength(){
    return element.items.every(lengthSuperiorTo5);
}
```

You can test if your string is a valid JSON string simply using `JSON.parse`

Try to play with the string to test different functions.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6n6woyyo/)

**EDIT : I've added the additionnal functions :**

[EDIT DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6n6woyyo/2/)

Comment: We should know which case failure which message

Comment: How can check the name property is empty or not?

Comment: let me check but it should be easy with the functions I already wrote :

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111410/discussion-between-rskmr-and-ashbringer).

Answer (score 0):

The callback will call multiple times, please add a "return":

```
   return callback(...);
```

For validate json in node.js, there is a good library: https://github.com/hapijs/joi